# how to calculate a frequency of a value in a table using Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Normally on my table I have those values (0,0,80,0,0,0,80,80,80,40) this table is named as qvValues , I want to have on frequencies table (5,4,1)

```
#include<QDebug>
#include <QList>
QList<double> frequencies;
QList<double> qvValues;
for(int i=0;i<qvValues.size();i++)
{

            frequencies.append(qvValues.count( qvValues[i]));


}
qDebug() << frequencies;
```

Comment: Please give example input and output.

Comment: just use `QMap<double, int>`. You need only one "for" loop.

Comment: Is your problem Qt related, or related to creation of the frequency table? I assume the latter, since the code you show doesn't actually have anything Qt-specific (`frequence` is a Qt container?). I suggest you create a non-GUI MCVE program, which generates and prints the table, and explain how it works wrong (show what it does, compared to what it should do).

Comment: for example , I have in qvValues thoses values : 0 0 2 1 1 , The frequency table should have 2 1 2 , 2 of 0 , 1 of 2 and 2 of the 1 , the frequency is a table who contains the number of occurence @John Zwinck

Comment: be aware that equal operator for `double` type (as any floating point type) is very treacherous. Depending on source of your input data this can lead to unexpected errors.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145563/finding-frequency-of-numbers-in-a-given-group-of-numbers

Comment: @JohnZwinck I work with the library Qt

Comment: I don't see what this question has to do with Qt. It is also difficult to understand what you want. You posted code, but can you describe what is wrong with it? What are you trying to do and in what way does your code not behave as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are from your example (comment).

```
#include <QMap>
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QList<int> values;
    QMap<int, int> frequencies;

    values << 0 << 0 << 80 << 0 << 0 << 0 << 80 << 80 << 80 << 40;

    int value;

    foreach ( value, values )
    {
        if ( !frequencies.contains( value ) )
        {
            frequencies.insert( value, values.count( value ) );
            qDebug() << "Value: " << value << " Frequency: " << values.count( value );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `QList` class to store your `qvValues`. You can use single `for` loop and `int QList::count( const T& value )` to calculate frequency of each value.

Comment: could you please clarify the idea , for example I have qvValues[0]=1 and qvValues[1]=1 , if I do for (int i=0; i<qvValues.size();i++) , for i=0 , it ll give me 2 but on i=1 , it ll give me 1 of 1 value , sorry but I didnt get ur point !

Comment: `QList<int> values;`
`QList<int> frequencies;`

`values << 0 << 0 << 2 << 1 << 1;`

`for ( int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++ ) frequencies.append( values.count( values[ i ] );`

Comment: normally the values I have are (0, 0, 80, 0, 0, 0, 80, 80, 80, 40)  and with ur code it gives me (5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 1) , the purpose is to have as the result (5.4.1)

Comment: could u help me with that please

Comment: @Oumaima Sh, put the solution in an answer to clearly see the code

Comment: I wrote the same code that u shared it , but my issue is frequencies values r going to be (2 2 1 2 2) like it counts the first 0 and the second 0 , my purpose is to have (2 1 2) in frequencies table , (2 of number 0 ,1 of number 2, and 2 of number 1 ) m going to edit the code so u can see , but it s the same as u showed me @pau

Comment: @Oumaima Sh, in the comment ABOVE you said that **the purpose is to have as the result (5.4.1)**. The code BELOW https://stackoverflow.com/a/51504702/786077 gives you that result with **the values I have are (0, 0, 80, 0, 0, 0, 80, 80, 80, 40)**